# Preview a column in pyspark shell

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**Short version:**

How to preview a column in the pyspark shell?

I have an object `a` of the type `pyspark.sql.column.Column` and when I do `a.show()`, I get `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`.

Wondering if there's a pyspark equivalent of pandas [to_frame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) functionality so that I can use `show()` after converting the column to a pyspark dataframe.

**Long version:**

I have the following data set as `df`:

```
+----------+-------------------+--------+
|    number|          p_efc_dtm|cus_type|
+----------+-------------------+--------+
|0000000000|2010-05-25 00:05:10|       1|
|0015195163|2013-01-03 19:01:10|       1|
|0018283269|2006-10-01 00:10:09|       1|
|0018988813|2012-11-29 17:11:45|       1|
|0020095510|2012-03-09 09:03:44|       1|
|0023688381|2008-03-13 00:03:51|       1|
|0024651256|2009-09-22 00:09:09|       1|
|0025647711|2015-01-13 18:01:27|       1|
+----------+--------------------+--------+
```

The following is done on the `df`

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

ws = Window.partitionBy(df['number']).orderBy(df['p_efc_dtm'].desc())

a = F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws)
```

How to see the contents of `a`?

---

I'm on Spark 1.6.0 atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong by doing

```
a = F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws)
```

`a` is just a reference to *max function call*

You should be doing

```
a = df.select(F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws))
```

Then `a.show()` should work.

If you want to see `number` column as you mentioned in the comment below then you can `select` both as

```
a = df.select(df['number'], F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws).alias('dtm'))
```

Or better if you want to see all the *original columns* then you can use `withColumn` as

```
a = df.withColumn('dtm', F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws))
```

Comment: Thanks, two remarks: 1) type of `a = F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws)` is `pyspark.sql.column.Column`, which was a bit misleading. I thought it is a reference to a column then. 2) Is there any way I can see the `number` column along with the `dtm` values? I wonder if  `a = df.select([F.max(df['p_efc_dtm']).over(ws), 'number'])` returns the corresponding number to the `dtm` value.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer by @Ramesh , in case if anyone is looking to preview a pyspark column in a dataframe: `df.select()` is the way.

```
df.select('number').show()
```